# Is there a project that can swap ETH and BTC using atomic swaps without having to deal with wrapped tokens like WBTC?

Tags: bitcoin, wrapped-tokens, monero

Is there a project that lets one do an atomic swap from ETH to Bitcoin or Litecoin or Monero without having to deal with wrapped tokens like WBTC(wrapped btc)? Basically a cross chain swap, without the need to deposit BTC to some service to produce a wrapped token and then swap to ETH.

Comment: Cross-chain swaps cannot be atomic in the strict sense of the word, as atomic means both halves of the trade would complete in the same transaction. You have two independent blockchain producing blocks independently, so there has to be co-ordination that breaks atomicity.

Comment: Have you checked Liquality? https://www.google.com/search?q=atomic+swap+eth+btc